# Ninject passing reference in constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, constructor, ninject

I am a noob with dependency Injections, I followed the tutorial and refactored my code to use Ninject. Here it is what I have (simplified).
Bindings.cs

```
 public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IConnectionToModbusCreator>().To<ConnectionToModbusCreator>();
            Bind<IInputProcessor>().To<InputProcessor>();
}}
```

Program.cs ;

```
static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var InputProcessor = kernel.Get<IInputProcessor>();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1(InputProcessor));
}
```

This start a form, the user by clicking a button start the program, here is the Form1:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly IInputProcessor _inputProcessor;

        public Form1(IInputProcessor inputProcessor)
        {            _inputProcessor = inputProcessor;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Test_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  ISequenceController sequenceController = new SequenceController( _inputProcessor)
            sequenceController.StartSequence();
        }
```

My problem is:

Is this the best way? I am worried by all the references I have to pass in the constructors, I tried to use a class Container which keeps variables with the objects instantiated and use them as properties but I cannot find sich method in any Ninject manual.

Comment: What you are doing is called **Constructor Injection** and it is _the prefered_ way of applying Dependency Injection. You should read [a good book](https://manning.com/seemann/) on this subject.

Comment: Thank you, I read a lot of tutorial and examples, I have some code to deliver, injection is not even demanded but I want to exploit the opportunity of making dome good modern code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program follows the Constructor Injection DI pattern which is good practice, but it has some issues which introduce coupling between your modules. The numerous calls to `new` should alert you.

- `Program` should not know about `IInputProcessor`. This is a dependency of `Form1`
- `Form1` should not know about `IInputProcessor`. It is a dependency of `SequenceController`
- `Form1` should not know about `SequenceController`, it should only know about its abstraction, `ISequenceController`

This can be solved by a better use of constructor injection to obtain less coupled code :

```
public class Bindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IConnectionToModbusCreator>().To<ConnectionToModbusCreator>();
            Bind<IInputProcessor>().To<InputProcessor>();
            Bind<ISequenceController>().To<SequenceController>();
            Bind<Form1>().ToSelf(); // in fact useless unless you add a scope, like .InSingletonScope()
        }
}

static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form1= kernel.Get<Form1>();
            Application.Run(form1);
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly ISequenceController _sequenceController;

    public Form1(ISequenceController sequenceController)
    {            
        _sequenceController = sequenceController;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Test_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sequenceController.StartSequence();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that looks so much neater!!

Comment: @Doraemon Glad to read it ! Don't forget to accept the answer so your question does not appear unanswered